# Bootstrap select too big

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors

I'm using ruby on rails and I have some inputs in a form. I use Bootstrap select to generate a div over them with this line in my .js file:

> $( '.selectpicker' ).selectpicker();

This works fine. Since my form is dynamic, when I update one input I have to run this in my .js file :

> $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');

Some times, when I have a few elements in the select this work fine but others, when I have more than 3 elements and I update the select to have one o two elements, the height of the div is bigger than the correct height.

(http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img674/3266/QTSpov.png)

I want this

(http://imageshack.com/a/img631/4894/OH2UMt.png)

I hope somebody can help me

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that you are completely removing the select options when this occurs? When it happens inspect the dropdown to see how many options there are. The refresh should update the size of the list. Make sure that the refresh is after the select options are completely removed.

Comment: First of all thanks, yes I removed the options before I added the new values. Later I refreshed the selectpicker. Also I tried to wait and run $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh'); in the console and it's the same. I inspected the dropdown and only has one value. I have this lines in the .js before I added the new values: var $select = $("#price_id"); $select.empty();